# Spring - save long json string in html hidden field

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hidden-field

I have a html form that contains a hidden input. I want to fill this input with json string(maybe long string) and then get it via `@RequestParam` in my controller. here is my javascript code(Note the form is generating by some event on the page):

```
var filters = JSON.stringify("some data");
//I used console.log for print out the filters and this is ok.

$("body").append('<form target="_blank" id="excel" action="/company/excel" method="POST"></form>');
$('<input type="hidden" name="filter" value="'+filters+'" />').appendTo("#excel");
$("#excel").submit();
```

And this is my action:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "company/excel", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void companyExcelExport(@RequestParam String filter) throws IOException{
     System.out.println(filter);
}
```

when the action executed, just "{" printed in the netbeans console. What is the problem?

I used `console.log(filters)` and it returned me:

```
{"search":false,"nd":1421663503100,"rows":10,"page":1,"sidx":"","sord":"asc","pageGridColModelList":[{"name":"id","index":"id","width":150,"sortType":"integer","hidden":true,"hiddenlg":true,"stype":"text","searchoptions":{"stype":"integer","sopt":["eq","ne","lt","le","gt","ge","bw","bn","in","ni","ew","en","cn","nc"]}},{"name":"name","index":"name","width":250,"sortType":"string","hidden":false,"hiddenlg":false,"stype":"text","searchoptions":{"stype":"text","sopt":["eq","ne","lt","le","gt","ge","bw","bn","in","ni","ew","en","cn","nc"]}},{"name":"createAt","index":"createAt","width":420,"sortType":"date","hidden":false,"hiddenlg":false,"stype":"text","searchoptions":{"stype":"integer","sopt":["eq","ne","lt","le","gt","ge","bw","bn","in","ni","ew","en","cn","nc"]}}]}
```

Comment: What is the client side content of `filters` on post?

Comment: It contains correct json value.

Comment: Have you checked that? Please post the first few chars of the content.

Comment: I will edit the post.

Comment: I believe the problem was double quotes in string ;)

Answer (score 0):

I changed:

```
$('<input type="hidden" name="filter" value="'+filters+'" />').appendTo("#excel");
```

into:

```
$('<input type="hidden" name="filter" id="filter" />').appendTo("#excel");
$("#filter").val(filters);
```

And now this is working.